# Ввод между строк в консоли c#. Net 7.0.12

Tags: c#

Как сделать так что бы в консоли был текст

```
Введите имя >> ... <<
```

Когда пользователь начинает вводить имя, последние кавычки пропадают

```
Введите имя >> Сем (вводит имя)
```

И по завершению печати последние кавычки появляются

```
Введите имя >> Семён <<
```

ах да ReadLine ещё переносит на следующую строку что в итоге

```
Введите имя >> семён
<<
```

Comment: Просто очистите все/строку и напишите нужный текст.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как-то так

```
Console.Write("Введите имя >> ");
(int x, int y) = Console.GetCursorPosition(); // запомнил позицию курсора
string name = Console.ReadLine();
Console.SetCursorPosition(x + name.Length, y); // вернул курсор на конец строки
Console.WriteLine(" <<");
```

Для древних фреймворков решение такое

```
Console.Write("Введите имя >> ");
int x = Console.CursorLeft; // запомнил позицию курсора
int y = Console.CursorTop;
string name = Console.ReadLine();
Console.SetCursorPosition(x + name.Length, y); // вернул курсор на конец строки
Console.WriteLine(" <<");
```

Comment: Спасибо конечно но моём привожении на телефоне C# shell-. Net IDE в System нету getCursorPosition ток getBackgroundColor и getForegroundColor и я не знаю почему так но спасибо что дал ответ так быстро, а и пк у меня нет так поэтому этим я пользуюсь:(        ааа я заметил что SetCursorPosition есть  а почему то getCursorPosition нет

Comment: @HMEi поэтому нужно указывать версию дотнета при задании вопроса, если она у вас древняя. Обновил ответ.

Comment: Версия .NET 7.0.12   блин красала я извини что нервы дал но я очень благодарен тебе спасибо я постараюсь писать вопросы правильно